# R flexdashboard gauge function won't change color

Tags: r, gauge, flexdashboard

I'm trying to make a gauge with a blue color using the flexdashboard package in R, however I can't seem to change the color of the gauge. It seems that it only comes in three preset colors of success, warning, and danger. My problem is that I can't seem to change success to blue. Here's my code

```
library(flexdashboard)

gauge(20, 
          min = 0, 
          max = 100,
          symbol = "%",
          sectors = gaugeSectors(success = c(0, 0.4),
                                 warning = c(0.4, 0.6),
                                 danger = c(0.6, 1)
          )                              )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify colors via the `colors` argument in the `gaugeSectors` function. As the help states `?gaugeSectors`:

> Colors can be standard theme colors ("success", "warning", "danger",
>   "primary", and "info") or any other valid CSS color specifier

So you need to add a `colors` argument like this: `colors = c("blue", rgb(0, 1, 0), "#CC664D")`

And also you made a mistake while specifying the value ranges in `gaugeSectors`: your minimum and maximum values are 0 and 100, so you need to provide values within this range:

```
success = c(0, 40),
warning = c(40, 60),
danger = c(60, 100)
```

Please note that the symbol `"%"` doesn't actually convert the value to percentage, it is just a string that is printed after the value.

```
gauge(20, 
      min = 0, 
      max = 100,
      symbol = "%",
      sectors = gaugeSectors(success = c(0, 40),
                             warning = c(40, 60),
                             danger = c(60, 100),
                             colors = c("blue", rgb(0, 1, 0), "#CC664D")
      )
)
```

[image: Result]